# Вывод из HashMap

Tags: java

```
Map<String, Object> defaults = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("id", 1);
map.put("damage", 0);
map.put("count", 64);
defaults.put("items", map);
```

Возможно ли вывести значение из id, damage или count?

Comment: если можно положить, то можно и вывести. логика же

Comment: Тогда как вывести?

Answer (score 2):

нужно использовать метод `get`, пример:

```
System.out.println(map.get("count"));
```

---

```
Map<String, Object> itemsMap = (Map<String, Object>) defaults.get("items");
System.out.println(itemsMap.get("count"));
```

Comment: мне нужно вывести через defaults

Comment: кастуешь и достаешь ровно также